# ML classification problem for matrix and distribution estimate for each cell in the matrix

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering, poisson-distribution

I am trying to think about a machine learning/statistical learning related problem. But would love to get idea from people in the forum about related problem/work/resource.

So, the problem idea is that, we are given lots of $N\times N$ matrices and we want to see if there are ways to group them (ie classify them). We don't know the number of groups present, so we want to find that out. Also, once we group them into classes, we also want to find out the distribution of numbers in each cells in the matrices.

I don't know if this is already an existing problem. But I heard there is a closed from solution for matrices where each cell has poisson distribution. Could anyone point to this as well?

Practical context:
So, we are studying a biological event in lots of different cell lines. And information about the way that event occurs in different cell lines is stored in matrices. So, each matrix (say $5\times5$) is generated for each cell line.  Each cell in the matrix corresponds to different things that can happen in the process of main event. And each cell stores  number of that specific thing occurring in that cell line. For example, consider the matrix generated for human cell line and it's $(1,1)$ cell. This cell corresponds to a specific thing happening in the biological event. And the number in the cell will tell the number of this "thing" observed in the human cell line. 
Now we have lots of cell lines and thus lots of matrices. We want to classify those cell lines by "similarity" of the matrices and also find out the patterns in each cell in once class/group.  Say, the above human cell line will be classified as a member of say group $A$. And in that group the matrix cell $(1,1)$ will have a $Poisson(5)$ distribution. The learning process should find out the it's indeed a $Poisson(5)$ distribution.

Comment: Could you tell us something about the practical context where this arises?  As it stands this is a very broad question!, maybe to broad.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I'm not sure it's too broad. I just don't know if it has a clear answer

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen , I just added a context. Hope it helps